# How do you read data from multiple files in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to read data from multiple .tsv files. The following gives a 1 x 1 cell containing all of the data, but is there a way to access the data directly? Since some of the rows don't have data, simply reading the cell doesn't seem like a good idea.

```
files = dir('*.tsv');
N = length(files);
for i = 1:N
   filename = files(i).name ;
   fid = fopen(filename,'r');
   file_Output = textscan(fid,'%s');
end
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Suppose you have 3 `tsv` files. These files will be read using the loop and the data will be stored in `file_Output` and this variable will be overwritten for every tsv file being read. In that case, (a) what do you mean by "1x1 cell containing all of the data"? and (b) by saying some of the rows don't have data, do you mean rows in the tsv files?

Comment: @Śubham Sorry for being unclear. (a) All of the data from each tsv file appears in the 1 x 1 cell in file_Output, which, as you pointed out, changes with each iteration of the loop. (b) Yes, some of the entries of the tsv files don't have data (not the whole row, just some of the entries within the row).

Comment: I see. By 'all of the data', you mean each file's data. Why don't you use `readtable` function instead of `textscan`?

Comment: When I try 'readtable', I get "The file extension '.tsv' is not recognized."

Comment: Use `readtable( filename, 'FileType', 'text' )`